# Subscript in Figure Captions

Tags: captions, subscripts

How do I make text subscript in a figure caption?

I've tried both `\textsubscript{}` and `\protect\textsubscript{}` but both throw errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For whatever reason, `\textsubscript` is not defined in LaTeX2e, but `\textsuperscript` is.

To make it work, you need to include `\usepackage{fixltx2e}`.

You can then use `\textsubscript{}` like you would in normal body text, inside a figure caption.

[[Source](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/latexusersgroup/GBFghkRZUAs)]

Answer (score 1):

To add on to Chris's answer: if you're using a recent version of TeX Live, the `fixltx2e` package is not needed anymore to use `\textsubscript{}`:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fixltx2e.sty

Package fixltx2e Warning: fixltx2e is not required with releases after 2015 
All fixes are now in the LaTeX kernel. 
See the latexrelease package for details.
```